# 'drawclosedpath' button not recognised by Dash when using 'modeBarButtonsToAdd' or 'modeBarButtons'

Tags: python, image-processing, polygon, plotly-dash

When trying to add non-default modebar buttons using modeBarButtonsToAdd, following error appears: 'must provide button 'name' in button config error occurs' yet correct name have been used according to docs?

Dash Version: 1.9 (these buttons are updated in Dash version 1.12

Docs for buttons in Dash framework:
https://community.plotly.com/t/dcc-graph-config-options/14672
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/modebar/buttons.js

Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

#simple image
img_rgb = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]],
                    [[0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 0, 0]]
                   ], dtype=np.uint8)
fig = px.imshow(img_rgb)

#config
config = {'displaylogo': False, 'modeBarButtonsToAdd': ['drawclosedpath', 'eraseshape'],}

#Dash application with graph
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig, config=config)
])

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

https://community.plotly.com/t/modebarbuttonstoadd-doesnt-appear-to-be-working-as-intended/32470 this works only for default modebar buttons

Any help would be appreciated, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Although this issue is a bit older, I would like to give an answer since I had the same problems:

My fix was to **upgrade** `dash_core_components` to the latest version which I think should be at least **version 1.10.0**. In this particular release optional modebar buttons were added (see the [changelog](https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md) and this related [pull request](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/4775)) that among others also include `'drawclosedpath'` and `'eraseshape'`.